# How do you disable client-side validation in ASP.NET core web applications?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have spent a lot of time sifting through bad answers to this question. Every answer I see is one of the following:

1. Uses web.config (this is retired in asp.net core, and it seems like there ought to be a method other than hacking in old features)
2. Suggests turning off javascript. The problem is, I need javascript running--I just don't want the client-side validation.
3. Offers code that doesn't compile and gives no context of where the code should go or how to make it so it will compile.

Am I trying to do something unsupported? This seems like it would be a standard part application testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client-side validation in ASP.NET Core can be disabled as follows:

Add

```c#
services.AddMvc().AddViewOptions(options => 
options.HtmlHelperOptions.ClientValidationEnabled = false);
```

in ConfigureServices() of Startup.cs.

Hope this helps.